# space winforms controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple winforms app with a column of several buttons. What is the nicest way to enforce that they are equally spaced vertically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag a rectangle around them in the designer so they all get selected.  Use Ctrl + Left mouse click to adjust the selection if necessary.  In the menu: Format + Vertical Space + Make Equal.

Comment: +1. Yay! _That_'s the way to do it if the spacing will be static.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the spacing dynamic (ie: it updates when the user changes the size of the window) the best approach would be to create a `TableLayoutPanel` with 5 rows (and probably just one column). Set its `Dock` property to `Fill`, and make sure each row has automatic size.

After that, you place your buttons on the panel, and it will do the positioning for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the top and bottom margins on each control to the same thing, and then drag them together using snaplines to line them all up.

Answer (score 0):

Change the location parameters in the properties windows to be proportionally aligned.